# Can i use single Enterprise licences with Magento 1 and Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-enterprise, licensing

In my existing `Magento 1` enterprise installation consists of **3 stores**. Out of 3 only 1 store i want to migrate to `Magento 2` other will be in `Magento 1` enterprise.

Is it possible to use single licence for `Magento 1` & `Magento 2`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any official information on this but it doesn't sound like you can buy a Magento 1 licence anymore.

> Licenses for new installations of Magento Version 1 are not available
>   anymore since Magento 2 has been launched last November. Existing
>   websites using  version 1.x EE will be able to renew their license for
>   3 years from the launch date of version 2. Then, they must upgrade
>   their stores to M2.

[Source](https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-enterprise-edition-license-cost/)

I take that as a no, you have to upgrade your existing licence.

But I suppose the only way to confirm it is to ask Magento.